# Can't able to run TestNG its show an error below I mentioned

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng, eclipse

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class testing.test
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at testing.test.<init>(test.java:8)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Welcome here. Please have a look at [asking a question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Your's is likely to get downvotes for [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) and probably other reasons... only dumping a stacktrace is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the stacktrace you have provided you will see that

`The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.`

So set up path to your webdriver in the code that is executed in your testng configuration to fix the issue.